# Application not launching on tappping the app icon on home screen

Tags: ios, launching-application

We have an application build for the several ipad users. The provisioning profile used for building this app has all the UDIDs. The application was working fine till last week.
Now the users are facing problem in lanuching the app. When they tap on the app icon, the application closes immediatly without showing any screen. 
The users are facing this problem after 13th March which was the start of DayLight savings time.So is it because of that? or the provisioning file has expired? 
Also my developer id has expired march end. But the provisioning is valid till june 2011. Is it the expiration of developer id creating a problem.
Need help..its production issue and i am not able to find out the exact reason.

Comment: If the answer provided below was correct then mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem because of provisioning profile. Either it has expired or has been disabled from the provisioning portal.

Comment: But normally if the provisioning is expired, on launch it gives an alert indicating that the provisioning file is expired. But no such error occured. How will I find that the file has been disabled?

Comment: You have an alert to inform you before the expiration, nothing for already expired profiles. To find the profile you need, look the app the bundle id in iPhone configuration Utility and update the corresponding profile.

Comment: Ludovic is correct. For a provisioning profile that has already been expired, the app just wouldn't launch.

Comment: hey i just checked the scenerio. The application for which the provisinoing is expired did show an alert.